# How to rotate rpi camera when using opencv for face recognition

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, picamera

I am currently using python3 with opencv for a face recognition project on the RaspberryPi. The rpi is installed into a smart pi touch housing which only allows the rpi camera to be mounted one way. I would like to be able to rotate the camera feed while running opencv.

I have tried to define the PiCamera and define the rotation but it does not work and causes the program crash.

```
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180

vs = VideoStream(usecamera=True).start()
time1.sleep(2.0)
```

Comment: Use Picamera 2 for latest  Bullseye.

Comment: Pi questions are better asked in the [Raspberry Pi Stack](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)